# Storing and sorting mixed data types

Tags: java, arrays

I am reading a text file containing athlete distances, with each distance on a new line. each athlete has 6 attempts for which a distance is recorded for each attempt. an attempt yet to be made has to be represented by String 'U', and a distance of 0 will be stored as a String 'X'.
I am currently initializing an array as follows:

```
Object[] distances = new Object[String 'U', String 'U', String 'U', String 'U', String 'U', String 'U',];
```

I am then iterating through the array and assigning the distances of type float to the array, or String 'X' to the array.
My questions are, is there a better way to store these values, and what would be the best way to sort them. numbers first in descending order followed by non attempts 'U' then 'X' (Distance of zero)

Answer (score 0):

> My questions are, is there a better way to store these values, and what would be the best way to sort them.

This is a typical case where OOP (object oriented programming) can help clarify the types of valid data and behaviors.

Have a base class called, e.g., `Entry` with derived classes, e.g., `NonAttempt` and `Performance`. Put the `float distance` field only in the `Performance` class. Create a singleton `Comparator<Entry>` object and use it to sort, e.g., an `ArrayList<Entry>`.

Answer (score 0):

How about you use Double array instead with
Actual values, Non attempts (0.0) and distance of 0 (-1.0)

```
Double[] d = {6.5, 1.3, 4.7, 0.0, -1.0, 9.2 };
```

To use with descending sort: Numbers first, followed by non attempts(0.0) and then 0 distances'X'

```
Double[] d = {6.5, 1.3, 4.7, 0.0, -1.0, 9.2 };
Arrays.sort(d, Collections.reverseOrder());
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(d));
```

Result

```
[9.2, 6.5, 4.7, 1.3, 0.0, -1.0]
```

You could use `Float` instead of `Double` too.

Comment: Thanks, i actually had done this originally, but am now required to produce output where non attempts are displayed as U and fouls (0) are displayed as X. Maybe i could do it this way and just change it when i call display, i.e if (d[i] == 0){system.out.println('U');}

Comment: Yep, this way you maintain the data structure with the appropriate values and display whatever is required. Also keep the sorting logic simple.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code for your requirement.

```
public class LineData implements Comparable<LineData> {
    private Attempt[] attempts = new Attempt[6];

    public float getDistance() {
        for (Attempt attempt : attempts) {
            if (attempt.getInfo().equals("U")) {
                continue;
            }
            if (attempt.getInfo().equals("X")) {
                return 0f;
            }
            return Float.parseFloat(attempt.getInfo());
        }
        return -1f;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(LineData o) {
        if( this.getDistance()>o.getDistance())
            return 1;
        if( this.getDistance()<o.getDistance())
            return -1;

        return 0;
    }

}

public class Attempt {
    String info;

    public String getInfo() {
        return info;
    }

    public void setInfo(String info) {
        this.info = info;
    }
}
```